# Unity Vector2.MoveTowards for certain amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I have a trouble with setting AI for my NPC. I wanted it to walk around the random points on my map and to run away from player when he's near. Escaping wors fine when I chase my npc, but when I stop they sort of bounce towards and backwards the player instead of just setting another destination...

Here's the code. I put runToRandomLocation() in the Update() method.

```
void runAway()
{
    if (!isDead)
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, -movementSpeed * 1.5f * Time.deltaTime);            
    }
}

void runToRandomLocation()
{
    if (!isDead) {

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position) > 3)    // if player is not near
        {
            if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, randomDestination) <= 2)   // when NPC is close to destination he sets another
            {
                randomDestination = new Vector2(Random.Range(-11, 11), Random.Range(-5, 5));
            }
            else
            {
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, randomDestination, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);   // NPC is just walking from point to point
            }
        }
        else
        {
            runAway();  // if player is near
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You really need a state machine for this, but your code that sets a random destination (the first if) doesn't actually do anything with that destination. It doesn't move anything.

Answer (score 1):

You generate a new random destination only when reaching the previous destination. What seems to be happening here is that after the NPS escaped far enough, it will continue to move to the last random destination it had **before** running away, hence it will return. Possibly in player's direction. So after one frame it is close to the player again, and runs away again. Then again returns to the old destination, and so on, in a loop.
What you need is simply to regenerate the random destination when finished running away.For this, you will need some state machine, as @Retired Ninja pointed out, but it is actually a very primitive one. For example, something like this should work:

```
private bool onTheRun = false;

void regenDestination() {
    randomDestination = new Vector2(Random.Range(-11, 11), Random.Range(-5, 5));
}

void runAway() {
    if (!isDead) {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, -movementSpeed * 1.5f * Time.deltaTime);
        onTheRun = true;
    }
}

void runToRandomLocation() {
    if (!isDead) {

        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.transform.position) > 3)    // if player is not near
        {
            if (onTheRun)
            {
                regenDestination();
                onTheRun = false;
            }
            if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, randomDestination) <= 2)   // when NPC is close to destination he sets another
            {
                regenDestination();
            } else {
                transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, randomDestination, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);   // NPC is just walking from point to point
            }
        } else {
            runAway();  // if player is near
        }
    }
}
```